# Android MediaPlayer crashes when started

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a piece of code that runs very well on some devices (Samsung Galaxy S2, Acer A510) but on others (HTC One S) it makes the MediaPlayer crash.
The code that causes the problems:

```
if(file.exists()) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(file));
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    };
```

I've tried starting it in the onPrepared callback or other ways of creating the mediaPlayer. They all work fine on any device other than the HTC.
The logcat error:

```
06-20 15:33:13.810: W/AudioSystem(6021): AudioFlinger server died!
06-20 15:33:13.810: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(6021): media server died
06-20 15:33:13.810: E/MediaPlayer(6021): error (100, 0)
06-20 15:33:13.810: E/MediaPlayer(6021): Mediaserver died in 16 state
06-20 15:33:13.820: I/ServiceManager(6021): Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
06-20 15:33:14.821: E/MediaPlayer(6021): Error (100,0)
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate them.

Comment: Hi user1469242 I am facing the same issue.If you have found the solution please let me know.